# How to show table field content in WebBrower Control on form in MS-Access?

Tags: html, ms-access, webbrowser-control

I want to show HTML formatted text on a form in Access.

I use a form which is bound to a table. The form has a Web Brower Control. The control source is set to a field in the table.

The Web Brower Control does not show what is saved in the field (this is what I want), it tries to interpret what is in the field.

If the field content is i.e. a file name on my PC and this file contains HTML then the HTML is shown in Web Brower Control on the form.

But if the field content is the actual HTML code (exactly the one which is saved in the file) then the Web Browser Control does not show the formatted HTML (this is what I would expect) but it shows my default search page searching for the content of my file.

I could work around this problem by saving all the HTML text from the table to files and then open these files in the Web Browser Control. But there should be an easier way.

I am sure other people tried the same before but I searched this forum and the web and I did not find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there is no other way than the one you suggested. 
WRite it to a temporary file and then display that file in a web-browser control.

Answer (score 0):

The control source for a WebBrowser control is the URL to be loaded initially.

Set it to `="about:blank"`.

Then in the code behind the form, assuming your control name is `WBControl`, replace the blank document with your desired content:

```
Private Sub WBControl_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
Dim doc As Object
If pDisp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE Then
    Set doc = pDisp.Document.Open("text/html")
    doc.Write ("<head><style>table { border-collapse: collapse } th, td { border: 2px solid fuchsia; padding: 2px 6px }</style></head>" & _
           "<body><table><tr><th>Pet Name<th>Type</th></tr><tr><td>Fred<td>dog</tr><tr><td>Garfield<td>cat</tr></table>")
    doc.Close
End If
End Sub
```